# How to tell if IE9 is forcing a page reload

Tags: angularjs, windows-7, internet-explorer-9

Is there any circumstance that would cause IE9 to force an unrequested page reload? If so how can I tell that this is occurring? Is there a log I can look at or custom event I should be looking for in event viewer?

I am troubleshooting an issue with an AngularJS web application that only exists in IE9, it works fine in newer version of IE and works on FF, Safari, Chrome. When testing in IE9 I see no errors in the console but I am getting redirected to my applications login page. This redirection always happens on a page reload, hence why I think IE9 is forcing a page reload.

Comment: Have you tried taking browser tools and looking into the "Networks" section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track navigation events, and the subsystems that invoke them, using the Network tool in Internet Explorer 9's F12 developer suite. Press F12, switch to the Network tab, and press "Start Capturing". From this point on, any further navigation events will be logged for your inspection.

Internet Explorer 9 uses an older version of the F12 developer tools, but you can still access the [historical documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx#networktraffic) for those on the Microsoft Developer Network.

The [modern documentation for IE 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx) is also available online, and much of what is shared about [the Network tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx) in particular is still helpful even if you happen to be using Internet Explorer 9.